# I am try to running child process fork with typescript from the dist folder but it's not working without using ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, child-process

hello everyone I am building a typescript node app and
I was trying to change my code to use ES7 instead of CommonJs because I need to make my code run only using the dist folder "typescript output" as a pure javascript project even if my typescript project doesn't exist.
After a lot of changes, I ran into an issue because I am using "ChildProcess fork" in my code and when I changed its path to "./dist/src/problem/index.js" instead of "./src/problem/index.ts" the process didn't start

here is my package.json

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  "build": "tsc --w",
  "start": "tsc && node  --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./dist/src/index.js",
  }
```

and my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.json",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.json"
  ]
}
```

and the part where I run the "ChildProcess" looks like this:

```
const childProcess = fork("./dist/src/problem/index.js");
this.childProcesses.push(childProcess);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run the app? Is an error message displayed?

Comment: all the project works just the process part not starting

Comment: Does the "./dist/src/problem/index.js" file exist? If it's not imported anywhere, TypeScript will not build it. You need to add it to your build process.

Comment: yes it exists I just checked the whole folder there 
export { ClusterSolver } from "./cluster-solver";
export { generateSolution } from "./precess"; 
and precess is where my process.on("message") locate